# Convert long to string form ip address

Tags: java

In the input programm set two ip address from Scaner in String form,
programm sort all addresses between.

example:

first ip: 192.168.0.1
second ip: 192.168.0.5

I need to get following
192.168.0.2
192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4

Here is solution:

```
private static Scanner sc;
private static String firstIp;
private static String secondIp;

private static long first;
private static long second;

private static final long lastIP = 255255255255L;

private static String convertHexToIp(long hex){
   String result = "";
   result += (hex>>24 & 0xFF) + ".";
   result += (hex>>16 & 0xFF) + ".";
   result += (hex>>8 & 0xFF) + ".";
   result += (hex & 0xFF);
   return result;
}

private static void ipSort() {

    sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Firtst IP");
    firstIp = sc.nextLine().replaceAll("\\.", "");
    first = Long.parseLong(firstIp);

    if (first > lastIP || first < 1111) throw new RuntimeException("incorrect IP");


    System.out.println("Second IP");
    secondIp = sc.nextLine().replaceAll("\\.", "");
    second = Integer.parseInt(secondIp);

    if (second > 255255255 || second < 1111) throw new RuntimeException("incorrect IP");


    for (long i = second; i <lastIP ; i++) {
        System.out.println(convertHexToIp(second++));
    }


}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ipSort();
   }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this in a generic way because ip-adresses come in different forms.

Comment: To see the ambiguity: which IP address would `22222` give?

Comment: when `l1=11111;` do you convert it to `1.1.1.11`, `1.1.11.1`, `1.11.1.1` or `11.1.1.1`?

Comment: Consider using [InetAddress](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) for you string to int conversions.

Comment: 2 Shloim 1.1.1.2

Comment: Please clarify your logic and motivation. I don't understand the algorithm you are proposing, and I don't understand why are you trying to invent a new algorithm when there is already a standard conversion from ip address to int and vice versa.

Comment: what if the long is `25512535125`, it should be `255.1.125.35.125` but you can't know when to add the `.`

Comment: user intput firtst ip: 192.168.0.1 second ip: 192.168.0.5. program should give 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.4. addresses between first and second IP

Comment: @IMBABOT This gets even more unclear with each of your comments. You need to clearly explain the mapping.

Comment: You throw away too much information here: `firstIp = sc.nextLine().replaceAll("\\.", "");`. After this step the problem has become unsolvable. You need another approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the value not in decimal but in `hex` long, and take every bytes from it, example:

```
class llong {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long ip1 = 0xFF01FF80; // 255.1.255.128
        long ip2 = 0xEE28BE15; // 238.40.190.21
        System.out.println(convertHexToIp(ip1));
        System.out.println(convertHexToIp(ip2));
    }
    public static String convertHexToIp(long hex) {
        String result = "";
        result += (hex>>24 & 0xFF) + ".";
        result += (hex>>16 & 0xFF) + ".";
        result += (hex>>8 & 0xFF) + ".";
        result += (hex & 0xFF);
        return result;      
    }
}
```